# Debugging an authorisation process in Postman

Tags: authentication, debugging, oauth-2.0, postman

I am testing an OAuth 2.0 authentication flow in postman.

- I used `Authorisation` tab, `New Access Token` button to start the auth process.

[image]

- Added the information in the form & pressed the `Requested Token` button. This opened a browser instance, in which I keyed-in the required credentials for authenticating a user.
- Once the auth steps are completed, I am redirected to the localhost page in the browser instance that was opened for auth steps. (Note, redirect url is given during the filling in of the form for request-token and is part of the specs for OAuth 2.0.
- This is where things go strange. On the redirected page on the localhost, I am still shown as not-signed-in, as there is no JWT (JSON Web Token) in the cookie/ local-storage.

[image]

- However, back on the Postman main interface. If I press the `Request Token` once again, I get the JWT, which is what I want.

[image]

**QUESTION:**

Why do I have to press the `request token` again to fetch the JWT token. Presumably the JWT token was not returned by the auth server, hence the browser instance still not signed-in? Does pressing the `request token` make another `POST` request to auth server to retrieve the JWT token. What is the process flow here?

And how can I debug this?

Edit:

Pressing the `sign-in` button again on the web app, leads to the auth server error page. I suspect this is because the server has the auth token for the user so does not let the user signin again?

Answer (score 1):

**How to debug Bearer token**
You can debug token received against client id and client secret using https://jwt.ms when you get token please be aware of properties:Issued at, Expired at, Issue to and issuer etc.

Now coming back to your shared details I am doubtful on Access token URL value it should be token provider url. The Azure token endpoint looks like: https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token

Once you get token then it checks authorization hence first you should get token and later it should hit to authorize endpoint.
https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/authorize

Also when you pass the token there are different flow and with Postman i believe it makes more easy to use Implicit flow.
Please refer different flow here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#page-8

For step by step approach on how to issue token using Azure AD please refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/get-azure-active-directory-token#use-postman-to-get-the-azure-ad-token

Hope it will help you to get token and continue with your further work.

Comment: I dont understand how this is relevant to my question. I am asking how to debug the process flow within postman to verify my assumtions I make about the token issue.

Comment: got it. If your concern is more on debugging postman traffic to understand where it makes a call and whether the requests are new and their outcome you can do so using Fiddler but for that you have to disable SSL certificate verification in Postman.

Disable fiddler certificate validation using  fiddler tools: